# Is the Form of the Good equivalent to the Form of the Intelligible Animal?

Tags: plato

I'm reading the [IEP entry on Plato's "organicism"](https://iep.utm.edu/platoorg/), which is the portrayal of the world as a universal animal. The article says that this entity participates in a Form of the Intelligible Animal. This Form would seem to satisfy all the following *desiderata* for a representation of the Form of the Good:

1. Most importantly from my own hermeneutic perspective, the world of the Forms must be a world-Form, i.e. the Form of a World (the world of the other Forms, no less). Given the above, that is this Form. I.e. the FIA satisfies the equation "the world of the Forms = the Form of the World."
2. Its participant is spherical, like the sun, and this Form is compared to the sun.
3. It makes the true-belief/knowledge distinction possible (this is another thing they bring up in the IEP article), thus in a sense exceeding the Form of Knowledge in value and power.
4. The article also brings up a relation between ethics and astronomy. So this Form, as the Form of the realm of the stars, is a Form of ethics, but is that different from saying that it is a Form of the Good?

**So is that it? Is that the Form of the Good after all?** 'Twould be so strange to think that the answer was there in the *Timaeus*, of all places!

Comment: however, is the world an intelligible animal?

Comment: The question reminds me of the Gaia hypothesis of Lovelock and Margulis: "The Gaia hypothesis posits that the Earth is a self-regulating complex system involving the biosphere, the atmosphere, the hydrospheres and the pedosphere, tightly coupled as an evolving system. The hypothesis contends that this system as a whole, called Gaia, seeks a physical and chemical environment optimal for contemporary life." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_hypothesis

Comment: @prof_ghost I don't literally think so, but it has since Plato himself been a point of unclarity and debate, what the Form of the Good was supposed to be, and this seems like a possible answer on the interpretative level.

Comment: go KO heideggerr haha @KristianBerry